# EAS Build Error on Configure Xcode Project Step

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, eas

I'm using a managed workflow with React Native/Expo on SDK46 and EAS version 3.8.0.

I'm trying to publish my first EAS Build to the Apple Store after migrating from Classic Build but keep running into this error on the Configure Xcode project step in Expo

```
Could not find target 'appname' in project.pbxproj
```

and this error in the build step.

```
Build failed
Could not find target 'appname' in project.pbxproj
```

I've tried looking for this file to see if I can add my 'appname' in project.pbxproj but could not find it.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the following issue: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1508
It helped me figure out a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after renaming my app.

What worked for me was running `npx expo prebuild --platform ios --clean` and then the eas build command, for example `eas build --profile development --platform ios`.

This generates a `/ios` folder locally and then you can check yourself the files. It also skips the prebuild step saying: `"Skipped running "expo prebuild" because the "ios" directory already exists."`.